# Visual Studio 2013 - How to debug a project within a solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I have a solution, I'll call it "MySolution". Within the "MySolution" I have two projects. One is a library and the other a console application. If I define a breakpoint at a line in the library code, running the console application with F5 (Debug) the breakpoint get's ignored. How am I supposed to debug my library code? I can't directly run the library code because it is a library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the reference to the library project, then re-add it as a project reference (not by selecting the DLL).

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea there was a difference, but it's obvious not it's been pointed out to me.